# Reuse TCP socket for HTTP requests

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to get the Tcl http package to reuse the initial TCP connection to a server to follow a redirect response. From the manual page I get the impression that specifying the option `-keepalive 1` should accomplish that. However, in my tests I observe that two separate TCP connections are used. This is my code:

```
package require http

# Redirect test page
set url http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html

# Make the HTTP library report what it is doing
proc http::Log {args} {
    puts [join $args]
}

set tok [http::geturl $url -keepalive 1]
if {[http::ncode $tok] in {301 302}} {
    # Determine the new URL
    set meta [http::meta $tok]
    set key [lsearch -exact -nocase -inline [dict keys $meta] location]
    set loc [dict get $meta $key]
    http::cleanup $tok
    puts "Redirecting to: $loc"
    set tok [http::geturl $loc -keepalive 1]
}
puts [http::code $tok]
http::cleanup $tok
```

This produces the following output, clearly showing that a socket is opened and closed for each request:

```
^A1 URL http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html - token ::http::1
Using sock560e29012cc0 for jigsaw.w3.org:80 - token ::http::1 keepalive
^B1 begin sending request - token ::http::1
^C1 end sending request - token ::http::1
^D1 begin receiving response - token ::http::1
^E1 end of response headers - token ::http::1
^F1 end of response body (unchunked) - token ::http::1
Closing connection jigsaw.w3.org:80 (sock sock560e29012cc0)
Redirecting to: http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/Overview.html
^A2 URL http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/Overview.html - token ::http::2
Using sock560e28f6e820 for jigsaw.w3.org:80 - token ::http::2 keepalive
^B2 begin sending request - token ::http::2
^C2 end sending request - token ::http::2
^D2 begin receiving response - token ::http::2
^E2 end of response headers - token ::http::2
^F2 end of response body (unchunked) - token ::http::2
Closing connection jigsaw.w3.org:80 (sock sock560e28f6e820)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

What else do I need to do to send multiple request using the same TCP connection?

Comment: Weird. I can reproduce the behaviour as you document it (with http.tcl in core-8-6-branch). Smells like a bug to me. Internally, when the second `http::geturl` kicks in, the internal state(connection) field is maintained as "close", there is also not socket mapping available. Worth a ticket.

Comment: @mrcalvin testing on older Tcl versions shows that the problem was introduced with http 2.9. I have opened a bug report.